# Why do different users get different migration flag suggestions?

Tags: support, flags, migration

I stumbled upon this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130846/why-does-everybody-use-yes-no-cancel-buttons

I felt like this should go to user interface/experience https://ux.stackexchange.com/

So I tried to flag it. But UX was not suggested.
[image]

Is there a way to just type in the SE a question belongs to?
How did @Chris Heald suggest the site?
Luckily he found a way so I could upvote his comment, but I still want to know how to do this myself.

**Why was he able to suggest UX while I was not?**

Or is it just a comment as @Roombatron5000 suggests?
If so, do such comments get as much moderator attention as the flag for migration does?

**What should I do the next time this happens?**
flag? leave pseudo flag comment? other?

thanks

Comment: @Roombatron5000 not quite, I rephrase the question to why different users get different suggestions.

Comment: *"I think Chris just left a comment stating that."*

Comment: @KevinB I see now, he added that after I posted the comment. Will add this to the question.

Comment: Add a comment telling the original asker where you think it should be asked, and  _if_ the question is off-topic but of high quality, use the 'other' option when flagging and explain to a moderator where you want the post to be migrated

Comment: Also, the list of migration options is fixed for all users, but the options change over time, based on which ones get used the most (AFAIK).

Comment: I should note that you should be somewhat careful when you direct users to other sites.  Most people tend to not have a deep understanding of the scope of sites they aren't active on.  You should be very sure that the question is going to be in scope on a site before suggesting it, rather than just guessing based on the title of the site alone.  Most all sites have narrowed their scope in some way that new users may not expect.  Directing someone to a site, only to be told by that site that the post is off topic, is a very disheartening experience.

Comment: @Servy this is why I want to flag it so it is brought to attention of a different (presumably more experienced) user for him to decide.

Comment: @null That's not how migration works.  And the number of people on SO that know whether any given question is on topic for non-SO sites is *very* small.  There aren't a lot of users that are active on multiple sites.

Comment: @Servy then there shouldn't be any suggestions at all !?

Comment: @null Personally I wouldn't be opposed to that.  That said, those few that are chosen are chosen because there's a strong track record of migrations to the target site being accepted.  If a migration target ends up with a sufficiently high rejection rate it's removed from the list.  Most sites only have 1 or 2 migration targets as a result of that.

Comment: A duplicate OF WHAT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He wasn't.  He just posted a comment saying that he felt the question belonged on another site.  He didn't actually vote to migrated it.

The list of migration targets is fixed for all (non-moderator) users on each site.

Comment: Is this the recommended way to deal with this? The question got asked on UX as a duplicate, leaving an off topic question on SO to be deleted. Wouldn't it be easier to just move the question over aka migrate it? If not, what's the point of the migration flag?

Comment: @null The question *was* deleted on SO.  If you want to know the proper approach for question migration see the links in the comments to your question.  I've simply answered the question that you actually asked, namely how did the other user cast a migration vote for UX.

Comment: I had one that belonged on programmers.stackexchange.com, but it's not an option, so I just didn't flag it :L

Comment: @MikeLyons they don't want you to think outside the box. They created a whole network of websites for people to ask questions and they made it very easy to create an account on one if you have an account on another. However, this does not imply that it should be easy to migrate questions throughout the network as well, because that's a whole different story, right? It's all about the people here, especially about  those writing algorithms to find migration suggestions and especially not about those providing such suggestions themselves. How dare you?

Comment: I mean, adding the flag as a link for people who find the question and answer further down the trail, would be #dope

Comment: @MikeLyons The *vast* majority of people that think their question belongs on programmers are wrong, as they don't properly understand the scope of that site.  Even if your question does belong there, a migration path to that site would be largely abused (there is historical evidence that this is in fact the case), which is why it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah Okay well that means I probably don't understand the scope of the site. Thanks.